# EmitMapper with object source type

Tags: c#, emitmapper

I need to use emitmapper with diffirent types.
For defoult it takes two generic types:

```
ObjectMapperManager.DefaultInstance.GetMapper<TSource, TEntity>().Map(source, result);
```

I need do something like this:

```
class Result { public string Name { set; get;} public int Age {set; get;} }  
... 
Result result;
object someType = new SomeTypes { Name = "TestName", Age = 23 }

ObjectMapperManager.DefaultInstance.GetMapper<object, Result >().Map(source, result);

Console.WriteLine(result.Name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't do this with EmitMapper. You could with [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/). The feature is dynamic mapping:

```
object someType = new SomeTypes { Name = "TestName", Age = 23 }

var result = Mapper.DynamicMap<Result>(someType);
```